# Is it possible to convert json(p) response generated by google-visualization-data-source-api back to datatable java class?

Tags: java, json, google-visualization

the jsonp response looks like

```
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({version:'0.6',status:'ok',sig:'2041370208',table:{cols:[{id:'coupon',label:'Coupon',type:'string',pattern:''},{id:'con',label:'Conversion',type:'number',pattern:''},{id:'convert',label:'Converted Carts',type:'number',pattern:''},{id:'displayed',label:'Displayed',type:'number',pattern:''},{id:'converted',label:'Converted',type:'number',pattern:''},{id:'status',label:'Status',type:'boolean',pattern:''}],rows:[{c:[{v:'test'},{v:0.33},{v:1.01},{v:3.0},{v:1.0},{v:false}]}]}})
```

just trying to get it working with spring testing framework. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

googled it and seems that the guys that develops google visualization java data source library says it is not supported for now.